# Can I make the color of the arrows on a line produced by the PSTricks pst-arrow package different from the color of the line?

Tags: pstricks, arrows, pst-arrow

The terrific `pst-arrows` package has lots of options for arrows on lines, but as far as I can tell has no way to make the color of the arrows different from the color of the line.  Is there a trick that will achieve that result?  (I know that the `tikz` package allows the arrow color to differ from the line color, but I am interested specifically in PSTricks.)

Comment: Which kind of arrow do you need? The default one?

Comment: @user187802 Yes, the default one would suffice.

Comment: I'll upload a new version of `pst-arrow` which knows the optional argument `tipcolor=...`. It should be available tomorrow at all mirrors.

Comment: @user187802 Wonderful! --- thank you.  If you are looking for some more work, it would be nice to have an option (TipOnTop?) that puts intermediate tips (via ArrowInside) on top of the line, rather than the line on top of the tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the uploaded version 0.02:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-arrow}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-4,-4)(4,4)
\psline[tipcolor=red,arrowscale=4]{<->}(-1,-1)(1,1)
\psline[tipcolor=green,linecolor=blue,linewidth=2pt,arrowscale=4]{|-|}(1,-1)(-1,1)
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]